# Silverlight TextBlock and textbox

Tags: silverlight, textblock

I'm trying to figure out how to change the font size of a textblock and textbox in Silverlight 2.0.  in code behind.  So far i've had no luck getting it done or find a referrence on how to do it.

thanks
shannon

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the [`FontSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.fontsize(VS.95).aspx) (also for [`TextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.fontsize(VS.95).aspx)) dependency property. This takes a `double`, as stated in MSDN:

> A non-negative value that specifies
>   the font size, measured in pixels. The
>   default is 11.

To set this in code-behind, you can do something like this:

```
// Assuming you have a TextBlock called 'block'.
block.FontSize = 18;

// ...alternatively...
TextBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.FontSizeProperty, 18);
```

Comment: Thanks for the replie. I may have an issue before i even get to that point.  I have lblAdjustFont.FontSize = 12 and recieve the message object refernece not set to an instance of an object.  This message is coming up when i run the app in debugger mode.  is there something i need to wrap that code with.  Is the textblock not created at by this point in the compile process.  The fontsize is being set in a event for a sliderbar.

Comment: it might be helpful if you had the xaml as well.
<TextBlock Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="379,18,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123.608" TextWrapping="Wrap" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" x:Name="lblAdjustFont" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="12" ><Run Text="Adjust Size of Text"/><LineBreak/><Run Text=""/></TextBlock>
<Slider Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,18,390,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" x:Name="slFontSize" ValueChanged="slFontSize_ValueChanged" Maximum="24" Minimum="12" Value="16" SmallChange="1"/>

Comment: Where are you setting the FontSize?